# How to create VR split screen using OpenSpace3d?

Tags: android, project, virtual-reality, android-augmented-reality, split-screen

I have been searching through internet on how to export an android application to play it in vr mode once I install it and run on my android device (using OpenSpace3d)

Can anyone explain on how can I accomplish this with *OpenSpace3d*?

So far I was able to create an application that does Augmented Reality, but I want it to have split screen and then stick it in CardBoard, or whatever

Maybe there is some button in *OpenSpace* that does this, but so far I did not find it

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the rendering/stereo plugit and choose cardboard mode.
for head tracking add the input/orientation sensor plugit and link the control event to the FPS plugit control action.